# How to sort an array of order 300000?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, large-files

I'm new to competitive programming and I came across ICPC Challenge on Codeforces. The first problem is https://codeforces.com/contest/1376/problem/A1 this and they gave file that has 30000 inputs. They basically ask you to sort list of integers in non-decreasing order.

I started off by implementing a bubble sort code and then gave the input file `sort.in` using `freopen("sort.in","r",stdin)` and then using `freopen("output.out","w",stdout)` function to create an output file. This worked fine for less inputs like 50-100 but when I gave the input file which has about 30000 inputs, the output file is empty. I did not understand why this happened.

I have two questions,

1. which sorting algorithm to use?
2. why the following code is not outputting the sorted array to `output.out` file?

link to the `sort.in` file: https://assets.codeforces.com/files/6f8518a9aaa619e7/sort.zip

here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    freopen("sort.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.out", "w", stdout);
    int n, c, temp, arr[500000];
    cin >> n;
    c=n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    while(n!=0){
        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
            if(n)
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
                temp = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        n=n-1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you’re asking two questions here: 1. what algorithm should I use? and 2. What’s wrong with my code. Could you edit the question to focus on just one of those? Also, search for other questions that are similar... this smells like it’s probably a duplicate of several other questions.

Comment: @Caleb I edited the question and what you just mentioned in the comment section is exactly my question. can you help me with this?

Comment: @jaychandra I assume the competion forbids use of the standard sorting function!?

Comment: Of the classical sorting algorithms quicksort is the quickest but has a slow worst case performance. If that is a problem then heapsort is recommended instead. Bubble sort is well known as the worst non-joke sorting algorithm.

Comment: @4386427 they did not mention anything, they just gave the file and we have to upload the sorted file. No need to submit code to them.

Comment: @john I'm new to all this stuff, so I thought of implementing with bubble sort, I'll try it with other algorithms and if that works, then I'll mention it here.

Comment: @jaychandra If standard sorting function are allowed, why write your own? Then simply use `std::sort` and - btw - use a vector instead of a C-style array. When using C++ you should not write code as if you were writing C code

Comment: Your code probably isn't producing no output it's just taking so long to execute you give up waiting

Comment: @jaychandra see https://ideone.com/fO2geu

Comment: @4386427 Okay, I'll try that. thanks :)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Writing a small file like that should not take long.

Comment: @AlanBirtles yeah, I think that's the problem, I'll wait for a while and let you know whether it worked or not. :)

Comment: @jaychandra I don't think it matters but try to add `fclose (stdout);` at the end. It could be a matter of flushing not happening until you call close. (hmm - not sure as I think it should happen on program exit)

Comment: @4386427 okay, I'll do that.

Comment: Make sure you have compiler optimisations enabled, you might have a long wait as your code needs to perform 900 million operations, a more efficient algorithm would only need 135 thousand operations

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm using std::sort function to sort them and it's taking a lot of time to compile and could you please tell me how to enable compiler optimisations?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm using g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Comment: @AlanBirtles Hey, the compilation was successful. It took time but all the elements seem to be sorted and stored in output.out file.

Comment: Add `-O2` to the command line

Comment: The only thing bubble sort is good for, is helping new programmers learn why you don't want to use bubble sort :)

Comment: 30'000 integers is really not that much. You should just use `std::sort`. If you want to you could implement [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

Comment: lmao @JeremyFriesner that's so true, I got to the point where I don't use bubble sort or selection sort anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually implement Merge Sort algorithms. Or just call the built-in C++ sort function.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    freopen("sort.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.out", "w", stdout);
    int n, , arr[500000];

    cin >> n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    sort( ar, ar + n ); 

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```